# Error 1005: Can't Create table (errno 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

```
ERROR: Error 1005: Can't create table 'db.pics' (errno: 150)
SQL Code:
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`pics` (
          `pic_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          PRIMARY KEY (`pic_id`)  COMMENT '',
          CONSTRAINT `fk_pics_houses1`
            FOREIGN KEY (`pic_id`)
            REFERENCES `db`.`houses` (`pic_id`)
            ON DELETE NO ACTION
            ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
        ENGINE = InnoDB
```

I have made sure the values are the same with the foreign key (pic_id) and the primary key in my houses table. I have created the indexes as well So i'm really not sure where this error is coming. If anyone can provide any other explain why the Error 1005 happens that would be really helpful. Thank you.

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `db` ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)  COMMENT '',
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 24
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`houses` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`houses` (
  `house_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `pic_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`house_id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_houses_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 25
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE INDEX `fk_houses_users1_idx` ON `db`.`houses` (`user_id` ASC)  COMMENT '';

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`pics` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`pics` (
  `pic_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pic_id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pics_houses1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pic_id`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`houses` (`pic_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created an index `fk_houses_pics_idx` and it works. Here is the updated code:

```
SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `db` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 ;
USE `db` ;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`users` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`users` (
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)  COMMENT ''
)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 24
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`houses` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`houses` (
  `house_id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT '',
  `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `pic_id` INT(11) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`house_id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_houses_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`users` (`user_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 25
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = latin1;

CREATE INDEX `fk_houses_users1_idx` ON `db`.`houses` (`user_id` ASC)  COMMENT '';
CREATE INDEX `fk_houses_pics_idx` ON `db`.`houses` (`pic_id` ASC)  COMMENT ''; /*This is what I just added */

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `db`.`pics` ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db`.`pics` (
  `pic_id` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pic_id`)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `fk_pics_houses1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pic_id`)
    REFERENCES `db`.`houses` (`pic_id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

So why this worked? When creating a foreign key constraint, MySQL requires a usable index on both the referencing table and also on the referenced table. The index on the referencing table is created automatically if one doesn't exist, but the one on the referenced table needs to be created manually ([Source](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)). Yours appears to be missing.

So, It seems that you were missing index for `pic_id` on `houses` table. Adding it solved the problem.